# Enable keycode output translation of ++ctrl+f1++ to <F25> instead of ++ctrl+f1++ to <C-F1>

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to convert keyboard key actions of bindings
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F13-F63</kbd>
to be similar to how it work in Windows 11 OS in WSL2 Debian in NVIM insert mode (for reference).

Migrating to Ubuntu made the <kbd>actionkey</kbd>+<kbd>F(key)</kbd> not work the same, outputting `<C-F2>` when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> unlike in the Debian WSL where it'd print `<F26>`.

I don't have enough specific terms to describe what I need here but I'm basically probably looking for the keyboard code remapping of WSL2 Debian in my Ubuntu 22.04 to be able to use my extended shortcuts in programs and configs inside of Ubuntu more or less consistently across the platforms.

I heard of `xmodmap` which I'm now researching but I'm trying to stay as native and as standard as possible if that'd just a 3rd party tool to actively alter the behaviour through another daemon that might not be a good long term solution, also I'm looking for somewhat standard, proved and tested mappings to now potentially run over other Linux philosophies and tools of other significant devs in the future as I'm not as experienced with the PC OS Linux world.
So how'd you go about doing that?

Comment: Have you tried `input-remapper-gtk` (applies globally to entire OS)? Can you clarify what you meant in your second paragraph where it said "not work the same outputting [...] where it'd print"?

Comment: I did now and it does seem to work and is interesting, but when I open nvim in insert mode and press a remapped say `F2` to `F23` it doesn't seem to print it unlike when I used to do that on micro soft and even and "emulated remaped" doesn't print any `<F20+>` output not I don't know how to point at it and how to disect it as it is quite invinsible and not to talked about in the channels I'm tuned to so not sure if that's something with the XKB(which is new to me),some daemon in ubuntu, a translator from the `/bin/bash` or an nvim version/conf I changed to make it work different from `WSL2`

Comment: So remapping in xmodmap keycode 191 F13 does seem to work ok untill I figure the XKB solution and in `input-remapper-gtk` you can map the ++ctrl+f1...++ keys but untill `KEY_F24` which is not sufficient, so How do you remap F25-F63 in the `input-remapper-gtk` then?